# RegExp for separated fields with fixed value

Tags: regex

I'm trying to verify a string matches a certain pattern:

```
#:XY1:XY2:ABC:::xy::
```

The part `#:XY1` is required, the fields and separators after that are optional. But if the third field is there, it has to be `ABC`. I am trying it like this:

```
^#:[^:]+:?([^:]+)?:?(ABC)?:?([^:]*:?)*$
```

But it matches also lines, which don't exactly have `ABC` as third field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this:

```
^#((((:[^:]+))((:[^:]*))?)|((((:[^:]+))(:[^:]*))((:(ABC)?)(:[^:]*)*)?))$
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an expression like:

```
(?x) ^#:[^:]+  (?: :[^:]+  (?: :ABC  (?: :[^:]* )*  )?  )? $
```

Altho this may be better (more readable) done using other programming constructs. Perl example:

```
my @l = split /:/, '#:XY1:XY2:ABC:::xy::';
if($l[0] eq '#' && $l[3] eq 'ABC'){
    # do stuff
}
```